# How do I get the signature design from embedded app?

Tags: docusignapi

When I checked the document in the email, I was able to select the Signature design registered in the sand box account. But there is no Signature information in embedded app, so how can I get it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxSHw.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Users/UserSignatures/getImage

```
GET /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/users/{userId}/signatures/{signatureId}/{imageType}
```

You need to know the SignatureId
for that you make first this call:

```
GET /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/users/{userId}/signatures
```

Comment: How can I bring my signatureId?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.
I don't know how to get the signatureId. How can i bring my signatureId?

```
OAuth.OAuthToken oAuthToken = apiClient.requestJWTUserToken(integratorKey, userId, scopes, privateKeyBytes, 3600);
        log.info("getAccessToken : " + oAuthToken.getAccessToken());
        log.info("getExpiresIn : " + oAuthToken.getExpiresIn());
        
        apiClient.setAccessToken(oAuthToken.getAccessToken(), oAuthToken.getExpiresIn());
        //UserInfo userInfo = apiClient.getUserInfo(oAuthToken.getAccessToken());
        userInfo = apiClient.getUserInfo(oAuthToken.getAccessToken());
        List<Account> accountList = userInfo.getAccounts();
        Account account = accountList.get(0);
        
        UsersApi userApi = new UsersApi(apiClient);
        userApi.getSignature(accountId, userId, signatureId); // I don't know signatureId
```

Comment: see my second URL endpoint which you make a GET to get all your signatures .That list would include the signatureId for each of them.

Comment: since you're using the Java SDK, you can call listSignatures() to get the list of signatures, which would include the signatureId for each signature.

Comment: If this helped, please mark either answer (mine or yours) so that it shows this question was answered. thanks!